# prevent django-allauth login on confirm email

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth to handle user registration in my site. I noticed a strange behavior. Let's say I register a new user in the site. That user get's a new email with a link to click. When the user clicks that link it takes him in the confirm page. There the user clicks the confirm button and users email is confirmed.

The problem is that as as a side effect the user is also logged in. I don't want that. This only happens only the first time I visit that page. If I visit that page again and confirms the email the user does not log in automatically.

My question is how can I prevent the user log in even in the first time he confirms the email. I searched the documentation but couldn't not find any setting to prevent this. Also I looked in the source code of ConfirmEmailView and I can't see a way to turn off this behavior besides manually commenting this line

```
resp = self.login_on_confirm(confirmation)
```

**Update:**

I think I found a workaround to the problem without having to fork or whatever. I just copied that class in my own views file trying to make sure I also imported all the other dependencies that are needed. Then I just deleted that call on login and the function that it calls. I hope I did a good job with that. After that in my urls.py, right before the imports for allauth, I copied the line that is used for confirm-email and redirected it to my own view. And now it looks like this

```
url(r'^accounts/confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', 'userprofile.views.confirm_email',
                       name="account_confirm_email"),
```

Seems a bit hackish but it seems to work well. I hope someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Well if you have personally checked the source for that view, and have confirmed that there's no way to disable this behavior yourself, what exactly are you asking? You should either replace `django-allauth` with a package that does what you want, or patch it the way you want it to work (though you're then stuck supporting your own branch of that package, and won't be able to directly install newer versions without losing your changes).

Comment: I am asking because even if I am struggling for more than 3 months I feel I am total newbie when it comes to both python and Django. My guess is that there must be others that maybe don't like this behavior and maybe the author has predicted a pythonian/django way to alter it. Something that my newbie eyes and brain can't catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the `ConfirmEmailView` from [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py) one can see that login is done only if `LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION` is true. In order to prevent login on email confirmation you should set `LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION` to `False` in settings.py.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option on the configuration **ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION**. It is True by default. Set it to False.

```
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = False
```

Comment: The above point by @jordiburgos is wrong. By default the setting is False.
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION (=False) source - [documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: When `ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION` was introduced, its default was `True`, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/0.16.0/allauth/account/app_settings.py#L186) and [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/0.16.0/README.rst). More importantly, this does not constitute a new way to fix the problem, so it should be a comment on the other answer. I understand you do not have the reputation to comment but there are no exceptions to the rule.

Comment: This option appears to have become `False` by default in [version 0.23.0](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/0.23.0/allauth/account/app_settings.py). It was `True` by default when introduced in 0.16.0.